# How to add and print prime numbers

Tags: java, primes

The idea is to type two numbers in the command line. The first being the start and the second being the number of prime numbers after the first number are displayed. For instance if the input was 16  3 the output would be 17 19 23

These numbers would be stored into an array. I've been trying many different things but they haven't worked so far.

I only have this right now

```
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{  
    int start =Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int count =Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    int[] prime = new int[count];

public static boolean check(int a)
{   
    if (a%2==0) 
    return false;

for(int i=3;i*i<=a;i+=2) 
{
    if(a%i==0)
        return false;
}
return true;
}
}
```

Comment: does this code even compile?

Comment: @ScaryWombat do your sentence even compile?

Comment: @FarmerJoe ha ha - very funny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check function is great. What you need is just a while loop to add prime number to prime[]

```
    public static void main (String[] args)
{  
    int start =Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int count =Integer.parseInt(args[1]);


    int[] prime = new int[count];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < count){
        if(check(start)){
            prime[i] = start;
            i++;
        }
        start++;
    }
    for (int p : prime){
        System.out.println( p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want a program to do something `N` times, you can use a loop.

Since this feels like HW I will provide an analogous problem.  Count `N` odd numbers:

```
int numbersToCount = 5;
int count = 0;
int start = 1;
while (count < numbersToCount) {
    if (start % 2 == 1) {
        count = count + 1;
        // opportunity to print number you are interested in
    }
    start = start + 1;
}
```